# I am writing a script that contains a name validation, but it keeps looping

Tags: python-3.x

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
userName = input('Please enter your name: ')

def NameValidation(userName):
    nameValidation = []
    print(nameValidation)
    nameValidation += username.lower()
    print(nameValidation)
    for x in range(len(nameValidation)):
        if nameValidation[x] not in letters:
            print('I\'m sorry, I can\'t accept that')
            userName = input('Please enter your name: ')
            NameValidation(userName)
NameValidation(userName)
```

This script will allow you to continue if you are correct on the first time, but if you give an input as string in the `userName` which any letter of enter string  doesn't contain in `letter List`, you won't be able to continue to the next part. When it loops back and asks you again what are your `userName`, even if it fits the requirements, the script won't let you continue onto the next part of the script.

Comment: Think about what happens if you enter "11111111" (hint: what happens _after_ you process the first "1"?). Also, _never_ loop over a sequence with `range(len(sequence))` and then access the sequence by index _unless you need the number of the index_; you can simply use `for x in sequence` in all other cases. Of course, the best solution in this case would be to not use an explicit loop at all, but use `any` with a suitable generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

your code keeps looping because of recursion. Let, Input is `sakib123` then your code take `sakib1` then Output `I'm sorry, I can't accept that`. so then you give again New Input, the nameValidation  is `new_Input + 23`. That's why it keeps looping. :)

You can try this code. :) :)

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
userName = input('Please enter your name: ')

def NameValidation(userName):
    nameValidation = ''
    print (nameValidation) 
    nameValidation += userName.lower()
    print (nameValidation)
    flag = True
    for x in range(len(nameValidation)):
        if nameValidation[x] not in letters:
            print('I\'m sorry, I can\'t accept that')
            flag = False
            break

    if not flag:
        userName = input('Please enter your name: ')
        NameValidation(userName)

NameValidation(userName)
```